# When zoom on touch devices page zooms in instead of map leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm working on a touch device and when the user zooms in which a pinch gesture, the page zooms in instead of the map.

I'm using a leaflet map with javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked for me was running Google Chrome in kiosk mode. In kiosk mode I set the parameter for --touch-events. After I tried this, I could zoom in and out without the page doing the same ting.

Answer (score 2):

One potential reason would be that the Map container may not have been active. Tap on the container and then try zooming in

Comment: I tried double tabbing on the map that works. But when I tried pinching it zooms in the entire page.